# How to exclude LatLng that is too far to include in the LatLngBounds due to max Google Map zoom?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

So I have to show as many markers as possible on my google map on Android. I use the following code to get the appropriate LatLngBounds to show the entire array of markers in one window on the screen:

```
val builder = LatLngBounds.Builder()
for (point in latLngPoints()) {
    builder.include(point)
}
val bounds = builder.build()
googleMapCameraBoundsCalculated(bounds, gMap)

private fun googleMapCameraBoundsCalculated(latLngBounds: LatLngBounds, gMap: GoogleMap) {
    gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, CAMERA_ZOOM_PADDING_METERS))
}
```

Now, the problem arises when I have markers that are in.... say Hawaii, and one that is in New York City.

Due to the very very long distances between the marker in New York and the markers in Hawaii (a bunch that are close together), the camera moves to the average of the markers (so between them) but **cannot zoom out enough to fully see all markers.** Ideally, I would like to find a way to exclude the marker(s) that are furthest away from the average (like the one in New York) so that the camera could zoom in on the markers in Hawaii (which are all relatively close together).

Essentially, I want to exclude markers that would prevent the majority of the markers from being visible due to the maximum zoom possible in a Google Map.

Thank you for any help provided, I have not found a solution anywhere to this.

Comment: "but cannot zoom out enough to fully see all markers" why not? please elaborate on why you cannot set low zoom levels.

Comment: You cannot back the camera up enough in a SupportMapFragment to be able to view, say, two opposing sides of the planet’s surface.